# SCRIPT1002 :Syntax error - IE10

Tags: jquery, asp.net, visual-studio-2012, internet-explorer-10

I am using .Net 4.0 freamworok on Visual Studio 2012. My web site I first started my website gives the following error on internet explorer 10. Other browsers(Google Chrome, Firefox..) is working correctly.

**JavaScript critical error at line 2, column 1 in .........

SCRIPT1002: Syntax error**

My jquery script file have set in Master page.

```
<head runat="server">
<script src="<%# ResolveUrl("~/") %>Scripts/jquery-1.7.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
```

I could not figure out the problem. Can you help me?

Comment: It is hard to tell without being able to see the full source code. Do you have a link to the page itself so we can debug it?

Comment: Thank you for your interest.
Site is not active. In fact, on iis is working normally. But I am getting this error when I run it on visual studio 2012.

Answer (score 5):

The complete text of the SCRIPT1002 message provides a clue, namely, ***Syntax error script section***:

> JavaScript critical error at line x, column y in siteZ.domainQ/mypage
>   SCRIPT1002: Syntax error script section

For me, my _Layout.cshtml or Index.cshtml, had references to ***virtual paths that did not exist*** for scripts or styles.

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>My Bubble</title>
@Styles.Render("~/Content/ErrorPathDoesNotExist/css")
</head>
```

Or

```
@section Scripts{
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/ErrorPathDoesNotExist")
}
```

I solved my error by removing or correcting the invalid virtual paths in the @Styles.Render or @Scripts.Render statements.

Please refer to Microsoft documentation about bundling, minification, and optimization for more information.

Answer (score 5):

Probably you already solved your problem. But there is still no accepted answer. So here is an another one.

I had the same error when i was using `const` in my javascript file. When i changed `const IDLE = 0;` to `var IDLE = 0;` my problem was solved.

Const is working in chrome, Firefox en IE 11.

For more information and browser compatibility see:
https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const

Comment: I had the similar problem with IE10.

Answer (score 3):

Excuse me, I do not know English well.

I think there are some problem in your code.

1. Use **single quote(')** instead of **double quote(")** before and after of server-side assignment; Because ***ResolveUrl*** method use **double quote** for its ***string*** argument and this sequence of double quotes, is against of XHTML Well-Form ness rules.
2. Use **equal sign(=)** instead of **hash sign(#)**. Hash sign should use in **data-binding** expressions.
3. You can pass the full resource path, to ***ResolveUrl*** method as its argument.
4. If the **Scripts** folder is in the root of the website, there is no need to use ***ResolveUrl***; you can just use ***"/Scripts/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"*** as value of the ***src*** attribute.
5. To ensure the accuracy and integrity of **jQuery**, download it again from its official website.
6. There is some JavaScript compatibility issues in IE 10. Use **X-UA-Compatible** meta tag to regulate IE.

Your code after apllying the previous points:

```
<head runat="server">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />
    <script src='<%= ResolveUrl("~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.2.min.js") %>' type="text/javascript"></script>    
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
```

Or (without server-side path resolution)

```
<head runat="server">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.7.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
```

Good Luck!

Some Helpful Links:

- [Official jQuery download page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj676915.aspx)
- [Specifying legacy document modes in IE](http://jquery.com/download/)

Comment: `I do not know English well` but then you write `If Scripts folder is in root of website, there is no need to use ResolveUrl; you can just use "/Scripts/jquery-1.7.2.min.js" as value of src attribute.` - that's pretty good English (should be `if *the* Scripts folder is in the *the* root of *the* website` and `as value of *the* src attribute`)

Comment: Thanks about your hint @mmcrae

Answer (score 2):

The way I solved it:-

1) removed some unused javascript code in my cshtml.
2) correct the script links to check if they are pointing to libraries that exist.
3) I was calling some javascript which did not exist like in Ajax.BeginForm , OnSuccess = "CloseWindow()", and CloseWindow() didn't exist,so either add the function or remove it.
4) Added this piece of code in web.config

```
<location path="~/Scripts">
    <system.web>
      <authentication mode="None" />
           <authorization>
                   <allow users="?"/>
             </authorization>
     </system.web>
</location>
```

I am not sure if doing the fourth step is required or not. But one of the posts in stack overflow says :The error was because the browser need to access Javascript in the script folder.
My project was asp.net MVC with entity framework in visual studio 2013.
Hope this helps.

Comment: I only added step 4, as I was denying access to unauthorized users, and this error went away.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem with my application. I removed unused script files from my ValidationScriptsPartial.cshtml page. I am developing Asp.Net Core App.